# Opensea source code

Tags: solidity, assembly, opensea

```
for (i = 0; i < words; i++) {
    /* Conceptually: array[i] = (!mask[i] && array[i]) || (mask[i] && desired[i]), bitwise in word chunks. */
    assembly {
        let commonIndex := mul(0x20, add(1, i))
        let maskValue := mload(add(mask, commonIndex))
        mstore(add(array, commonIndex), or(and(not(maskValue), mload(add(array, commonIndex))), and(maskValue, mload(add(desired, commonIndex)))))
    }
}
```

can anyone explain these code for me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sure,

This code is part of the [guardedArrayReplace](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/0x-fee-wrapper/blob/5c7949fbb848be8aa5da5acb0c4e45a157f00722/contracts/lib/ArrayUtils.sol#L30) function, which essentially overwrites the content of a byte array with the content of another, but it may vary depending on the provided mask.

As a reminder on bitwise operations, working on 2 bytes values for the explanation :

let's say we have an `array` value of `0x1234` and a desired value of `0xaabb` with a mask of `0x00FF`. The mask will be used to select which bits we want to take from `desired` to write to `array`. Reversing the mask gives you which bits you want to preserve from `array`.

`array & not(mask)` = `0x1200` : discarding the value not pointed by the mask in `array`.

`desired & mask` = `0x00bb` : keeping only the value pointed by the mask in `desired`.

Combining those two : `or(array & not(mask), desired & mask` we get 0x12bb. Where we effectively updated `array` with the values from `desired` as pointed by `mask`.

```
for (i = 0; i < words; i++) {
    /* Conceptually: array[i] = (!mask[i] && array[i]) || (mask[i] && desired[i]), bitwise in word chunks. */
    assembly {
        let commonIndex := mul(0x20, add(1, i))
        let maskValue := mload(add(mask, commonIndex))
        mstore(add(array, commonIndex), or(and(not(maskValue), mload(add(array, commonIndex))), and(maskValue, mload(add(desired, commonIndex)))))
    }
}
```

This part is working on 32 bytes chunks even though the underlying data is divided in bytes. It's just a way of treating 32 elements at once as long as it's possible.

```
let commonIndex := mul(0x20, add(1, i))
```

Computes the **memory** index (or address) of the 32 bytes chunk we are dealing with at a specific iteration of the loop. At the ith iteration, we are targeting the data at memory index `0x20 (32) * (i + 1)`. The `+ 1` is just used to skip the first 32 bytes which hold the length of the array.

```
let maskValue := mload(add(mask, commonIndex))
```

Uses the fact that `array` , `mask` and `desired` must have the same length (see the require statements in the function) and simply loads the 32 bytes from the `mask` array that should be applied when overwriting that specific portion of `array` with the one from `desired`.

```
mstore(add(array, commonIndex), or(and(not(maskValue), mload(add(array, commonIndex))), and(maskValue, mload(add(desired, commonIndex)))))
```

We'll break that one down :

The `mstore` arguments are :

- `add(array, commonIndex)`
- `or(and(not(maskValue), mload(add(array, commonIndex))), and(maskValue, mload(add(desired, commonIndex))))`

The first one being the address at which we are going to write those modified 32 bytes, the second one is the value to write.

`or(and(not(maskValue), mload(add(array, commonIndex))), and(maskValue, mload(add(desired, commonIndex))))`

Where `and(not(maskValue), mload(add(array, commonIndex)))` takes the value from `array`, and keep only the bytes not marked by `maskValue`. On the other side, `and(maskValue, mload(add(desired, commonIndex)))` takes the value from `desired` and keep only the bytes marked by `maskValue`. The surrounding `or` merges both what we want to keep from `array` and what we want to take from `desired`.

This value is then written in `array` at the adequate 32 byte slot.

The process is repeated as many times as possible, that way, updating an array with a size of 64 bytes (32 * 2) would only take 2 iterations, instead of 64 if you were to do it byte by byte.

I hope that answers your question.